# AWS full node requirements and querying transactions

Tags: nodes

I would like to work with the Ethereum blockchain and be able to get transactions associated with an address. I believe I cannot use the fast sync mode and need to have a fully valditating node?

Do you have advices for the AWS specs?

Do I have to maintain an index to get list of transactions like
https://etherscan.io/address/0x281055afc982d96fab65b3a49cac8b878184cb16

or it possible to access it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can actually use the fast syncmode and you will still be able to get transactions associated with an address using events. [Here's](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/will-i-be-able-to-get-past-contract-events-through-rpc-if-i-use-geth-fast/9447) a similar answer.

I have tested working Geth with option `cache=4000` on t2.large (with 8GB RAM) and the CPU usage is around 50% until the node synchronizes completely, after which the CPU utilization is fairly low. You should be concerned more about the storage I think.

Answering your third question, it's mainly a software design and need-based issue. If you want to open an API route that's going to make quick requests, or if you're tracking a lot (or say all the addresses), then it'll be a better idea to 'index' the transactions. Etherscan can't do that on the fly requesting the node for tracing the transactions either. 
However, if you do not have a huge traffic/throughput requirements, you don't necessarily need to index the transactions. Think about it that you'll have to maintain an almost the same size of database to index the transactions.